# google map multiple marker with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How to make multiple marker in google map, using json data.
i have tried with single marker it is working
but no with multiple marker.

Here is the code for single Marker (IT IS WORKING)

```
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lang=position.coords.longitude;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);

 var myMapOptions = {
   zoom: 12
   ,center: myLatlng
   ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 };

 var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
 var image = "images/tag.png"; //IMAGE TAG
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 map: theMap,
 draggable: false,
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang),
 visible: true,
 icon: image,
 title:restaurantName // Title
});

 var myOptions = {
  content: ""
 ,disableAutoPan: false
 ,maxWidth: 0
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -110)
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(140, 110)
 ,zIndex: null
 ,boxStyle: { 
  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
  ,opacity: 0.90
 }
 ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
 ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
 ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
 ,isHidden: false
 ,pane: "floatPane"
 ,enableEventPropagation: false
 };
```

This is to make a description when marker is clicked

```
var contentString = '<div class="map_anotaion_title">Description</div>'; //Address on pin click

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
 });
 infowindow.open(theMap,marker); 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    infowindow.open(theMap,marker);     
 });
```

Here is the code i trying with Multiple Marker Load from JSON ( IT IS NOT WORKING)

```
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lang=position.coords.longitude;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);

 var myMapOptions = {
   zoom: 12
   ,center: myLatlng
   ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 };

 var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
 var image = "images/tag.png";

$.getJSON('http://myweb.com/services/get_loc_komp.php', function(json1) {
          $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 map: theMap,
 draggable: false,
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latd,data.lotd),
 visible: true,
 icon: image,
 title:data.street // Title
});

          });
        });
var myOptions = {
  content: ""
 ,disableAutoPan: false
 ,maxWidth: 0
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -110)
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(140, 110)
 ,zIndex: null
 ,boxStyle: { 
  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
  ,opacity: 0.90
 }
 ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
 ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
 ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
 ,isHidden: false
 ,pane: "floatPane"
 ,enableEventPropagation: false
 };

var contentString = '<div class="map_anotaion_title">Description</div>'; //Address on pin click

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
 });
 infowindow.open(theMap,marker); 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    infowindow.open(theMap,marker);     
 });
```

Pls help me anybody

thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569854/adding-multiple-markers-in-google-maps-api-v2-android

Comment: Are you sure that this relates to the android tag?

Comment: yes. i put this code in android aps

Comment: Can you show us an example JSON that is returned from the API endpoint? E.g. what is a sample data that you get from `json1` in the `getJSON()` callback?

Comment: Thank you @Terry , your simple question, wake me up..i make mistake while capturing json variables..thank you si much, its work now

Answer (score 0):

its working now, 
thank you @terry

this is my code :

```
$.getJSON('http://myweb.com/services/get_loc_komp.php', function(data) {

all_address = data.items;

         $.each(all_address, function(index, adress) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: theMap,
         draggable: false,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(adress.latd,adress.lotd),
         visible: true,
         icon: image,
         title:adress.street // Title
});

                var contentString="";
                var infowindow="";
                     var contentString = '<div class="map_anotaion_title">'+adress.street+'</div>'; //Address on pin click


                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString
                 });
                 infowindow.open(theMap,marker); 
                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infowindow.open(theMap,marker);     
                 });    

          });
        });
```