# Show text info for all markers, android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i'm trying to show text for all markers. 
I've seen this solution: 
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/
And checked the 
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

I've succeeded to get to this situation:
[image: prob]

But as you can see the text is on the icon, and I want it to have a bit of margin button - and I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the code I used to make the marker:

```
 Context context = getApplicationContext();
                TextView text = new TextView(context);
                text.setText(pilotName);
                text.setTextSize(18);
                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(context);
                generator.setContentPadding(20,20,0,0);
                generator.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.aircraft));
                generator.setContentView(text);
                Bitmap icon = generator.makeIcon();
                MarkerOptions tp = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                mMap.addMarker(tp);
```

I've also tried: `text.setPadding(40, 40, 0, 0);`
And `generator.setContentPadding(20,20,0,0);`
to see if it solves it... and it didn't work

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use a layout and then render a drawable from that layout.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947084/how-to-show-all-marker-labels-in-google-maps-simultaenously/48949960#48949960.  Once you have that set up then you can customize the layout to your satisfaction.

Comment: I'll check it out soon and update if it worked. Thanks