# Show multiple markers using the geo: intent to display a map at a specified location and zoom level

Tags: android, dictionary, android-intent, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I want to display some markers using the geo: intent to display a map at a specified location and zoom level. But I don't know how to add my markers here? Can somebody help me with this?

```
// Creates an Intent that will load a map of San Francisco
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Thanks in advice for some help.

Comment: [Adding a Map with a Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker)

Comment: But here I would need an Google Api Key. I wanted to put some markers in above map on only putting the coordinates in it. Does that only work with your solution and the api-Key?

Comment: Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569854/adding-multiple-markers-in-google-maps-api-v2-android)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try the following example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=37.7749,-122.4194 (San Francisco)"));
// the following line should be used if you want use only Google maps
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, but it only shows 1 Marker. What about showing 2 or 3 Markers? Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: No, its not solved, because your answer is good for 1 Marker, but I would like to have more than 1 Marker.